# Shell concept in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am novice in cakephp.Please explain me the concept to shells in cake php and how it is helpful in web development?

I have read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html.But still I am not getting the idea of shells in relevance to web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shells are relevant. You can basically write any shell command and script you need. There are other shells like the migration shell coming with the migrations plugin.

I've seen silly attempts were people used cron and wget to call an URL to execute a task every X minutes. That's the perfect example where a shell is the proper solution.

There are plenty of use cases for shells, queuing (emails for example), data conversion, data import... Everything that runs for a long time or checks something like the queuing can be done as a shell. Shells can be also utility or development tools as well. You can even control with the "[nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29)" command how much CPU load a program is allowed to use.

So for example if you have audio or video conversion after upload this should run in the background. The shell task will look for new uploads and when it finds some convert the data in the desired format and never use up more than 20% CPU load for example and by this it won't make the site unresponsive by using 100% CPU load.

Comment: Thannks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to CakePHP, I'll suggest to check 'bake' console command. ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html ).

It can help you to generate models, controllers, views, migrations and many others.

It's a powerful tool that will save you a lot of time. When you are generating the model using 'bake' command, it will automatically detect all the tables in your database, work out the database relationship and you can also define the validation for each field.

Here is video tutorial on YouTube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kfu58OozDrM

Comment: Thanx You for your help.I am familiar with bake concept.I want to know how shells are  relevant to web development?